# Method to Match Multiple Columns Dynamically in one Table to another Table (e.g. Address, City, State, Zip)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, string-matching

I'm using SQL Server 2008 w T-SQL syntax. I know a little bit of C# and Python - so possibly could venture into those paths to make this work.

The Problem:

I have multiple databases where I have to match customers within each Database to a "Master Customer" file.

It's basically mapping those customers at those distributors to the supplier level.

There are 3-8 million customers for each Database (8 of them) that have to be matched to the Supplier Table (1800 customers).

I'd rather not have to do a Excel "Matching game" for about 3-4 weeks (30 million customers). I need some shortcuts as this is exhaustive.

This is one Distributor Table:

```
select
    master_cust_Num, 
    master_cust_name, 
    cust_shipto_name, 
    cust_shipto_address, 
    cust_shipto_address_2, 
    cust_shipto_city, 
    cust_shipto_state, 
    cust_shipto_zip
from 
    Distributor.sales
group by
    master_cust_Num, 
    master_cust_name, 
    cust_shipto_name, 
    cust_shipto_address, 
    cust_shipto_address_2, 
    cust_shipto_city, 
    cust_shipto_state, 
    cust_shipto_zip
```

This is a small snippet of what the table yields:

[image]

And I'd have to match that to a table that looks like this:

[image]

Basically I need a function that will search out the address lines in the Distributor DBs for a matches or closest match(es). I could do a case when address like '%birch%' to find all 'birch' street matches when distributor.zip_code=supplier.zip_Code" but I'd rather not have to write in each of those strings within the like statements.

Is there an XML trick that will pick out parts within the multiple distributor address columns to match that of the supplier address column? (or maybe 1 at a time, if that's easier)

Can I do a like '%[0-9][A-Z]% type of search? I'm open to best practices (will awards pts) as to tackle this beast. I guess I'mt not even sure how to tackle this other than brute force by grouping by zip codes and working street matches from there.

The matching/searching 'like' function (or XML) or whatever would have to try to dynamically match one column say "Birch St" in the Supplier Address column to find all matches of "Birch Ave" "Birch St" "Birch Ave" "Birch" that had that same zip.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SQL Server Integration Services?  If so, you could use the SSIS Fuzzy Lookup to look up customers in the master customer table by address.

If you're not familiar with that feature of SSIS, it will let you specify columns to compare, how many potential matches to return, and a threshold that a comparison has to meet to be reported to you.

Here's an article specifically about matching addresses:  [Using Fuzzy Lookup Transformations in SQL Server Integration Services](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-fuzzy-lookup-transformations-in-sql-server-integration-services)

If you don't have it available ... well, then we start getting into implementing your own fuzzy-matching algorithm.  Which is quite possible:  it's just a bit more laborious.

Comment: Ann, thank you. I've never used SSIS before - but my company does have the software - so I'm going to give it a whirl.